# Refusal to run after skying the ball

Tags: cricket

Consider the situation where a run is required off the last ball. The ball is legitimate, and the batsman tries to go for a six, and is caught in the deep.
I have seen several instances where this happens and the batsman just stares at the ball go into the hands of the fielder.
My question is:

> Shouldn't he run as fast as he can, just in case he can get to the other end before the ball is taken?

Note that this is only for skied catches that I'm talking about.
If the ball takes ~2.5s to come down and the length of the pitch is 22 yards, the required speed comes out to be ~8m/s, which is achievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't he run as fast as he can, just in case he can get to the other end before the ball is taken?

By this you want to say that a batsman should take a run before he cought out. So they win before he get out.

As per [LAW 18 (SCORING RUNS)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/)

> Section
> **9. Runs scored when a batsman is dismissed**
>
> When a batsman is dismissed, any runs for penalties awarded to either side shall stand. **No other runs shall be credited to the batting side**, except as follows.
>
> If a batsman is,
>
> (a) dismissed **Handled the ball**, the batting side shall also score the runs completed before the offence.
>
> (b) dismissed **Obstructing the field**, the batting side shall also score the runs completed before the offence.
>
> If, however, the obstruction **prevented a catch** from being made, **no runs other than penalties** shall be scored.
>
> (c) dismissed **Run out**, the batting side shall also score the runs completed before the wicket was put down.
>
> If, however, a striker who has a runner is himself dismissed Run out, no runs other than penalties shall be scored. See Law 2.8 (Transgression of the Laws by a batsman who has a runner).

So even if batmen complete required runs before a stiker get cought out by a filder, they can't win the match.

But yes batsmen should try to complete required runs and should hope a catch to be dropped.

---

**Update:**

As [suggested by @Bogdanovist:](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/refusal-to-run-after-skying-the-ball#comment-5320)

It's hard to judge run outs where stumps are even less than 1 meter away from the crease, then how can they judge catch out and completed runs when the field is away up to 100 meters from the crease.

Comment: This is correct. To explain further, think about why this is rule is in place. If you got credited with runs made between the wickets before the catch was taken, the umpires would need to judge whether a batsmen got home before a field up to 100 meters away  caught the ball. It's hard enough judging run outs when the stumps are less than 1 metre from the crease! So this would be completely impossible for the umpires to rule on accurately.

Comment: @Bogdanovist - Fair enough. Editing :)